# Hibernate add entity with child entity id

Tags: java, hibernate

My Objects

**State.java**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "STATE")
public class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

**City.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class City extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", nullable = false)
    private State state;
}
```

I want to add a new city where i have city name and state id. To add a new city I perform

- get state from state table. `State state = (State) hibernateManager.get(State.class, id);`
- Set state in city. `city.setState(state)`
- Perform save Operation on city. `hibernateManager.save(city);`

As I have the state id and in city table only Id is going to be store. So Is there is any way so that without making a call to state table simply `save(city)` will do the same task.

Comment: @R.J Thanks for response. Except JDBC is there any alternative in hibernate.

Comment: @R.J Already tried but that will give an exception.

Comment: @R.J what do you mean by live state. As city contains only state id. Does it matter wether state object is changed or not(except deletion case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use STATE_ID column individually and for mapping to state. Then for saving city you can simply set the stateId. Note the attributes used in @JoinColumn (insertable = false, updatable=false) to avoid the famous repeated column exception.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", insertable = false, updatable=false)
private State state;

@Column(name = "STATE_ID")
private Long stateId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the State object handy, you would have to retrieve it from the database before you can assign it to your City object.

One option is: you could alter your model such that instead of holding a reference to State, it just holds a reference to the State's ID:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class City extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "STATE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String stateId;
}
```

and then your operation becomes:

```
city.setStateId(stateId);
hibernateManager.save(city);
```

The pitfall of doing this, though, is that to retrieve the object graph that contains both city and state, i think you have to do an explicit Join on the two tables.

edit-- 
since I don't have enough reputation to comment yet: to RJ's answer, I think that would throw a Hibernate exception if an object with that STate ID already exists in the db (which, in this case, it seems like it does already exist), since you can't have two objects with the same primary keys.

Comment: thnak for the response. But this will voilate hibernate usage and retriving of data is will be complicated.

Comment: ah okay. :) is there any reason in particular that you want to eliminate retrieving the State object? It shouldnt really be that much overhead seeing its a simple get

Comment: firstly I had to make a db call which is not required as I have stateId, which is finally save in db not whole state. This question is simple in this case. But In my application point of vieew there are lots of interrelations so in taht case so many db calls.